# Instagram API Permission is "Declined"

Tags: permissions, instagram

I'm working on integration with Instagram API.
And need to post comments under my own media, and I know that I need to get permission for this action. And I submit a Permission request in my API client Permissions tag, but it's declined two weeks after submission. And reminds me that "he use case descrbied in your submission notes, screencast and website is not a valid use case that we allow on our Platform. "

Is there anybody got the permissions? Could you please share some experience with me?

Comment: What does your app do?

Comment: Same issue with rejection from Instagram API team. This seems like a common problem. Need solution, please

Comment: I also have same issue and same reason of rejection. Do you get solution?